# Access ignores INNER JOIN or WHERE clause in sub queries

Tags: sql, ms-access

I use this kind of query:

```
SELECT element, Category FROM TableA, AllowedCategories
WHERE TableA.Category = AllowedCategories.Category
```

TableA's data looks like this:

```
element    Category
el1        Cat1
el2        Cat1
el3        Cat1
el4        Cat2
el5        Cat3
```

AllowedCategories is a list of Category. Only values of TableA that are inside AllowedCategories must be shown in the query.

It is working great for the first query. It does filter elements that are not inside AllowedCategories table. However, when I do a subquery out of this one, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT element, Category FROM TableA, AllowedCategories
    WHERE TableA.Category = AllowedCategories.Category) As temp1
```

Categories are not filtered anymore. What is wrong, how can this problem be worked arround?

(File extension is a .mdb)

**UPDATE:** I wrote my query again, and it somehow worked. I still do not have any idea of what could have caused this problem, but I tought that when a subquery is being queried, it is not losing its filters. It is indeed a very weird behavior from MS-Access. Querying my queurie with a simple

```
SELECT * FROM subquery
```

was giving me more records than I had in my subquery. Hopefully, rewriting the query again made it work.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an older style of writing your query. I would suggest using the explicit INNER JOIN syntax:

```
SELECT element,
       Category
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN AllowedCategories 
ON TableA.Category = AllowedCategories.Category
```

Or alternatively:

```
SELECT element, category
FROM TableA
WHERE Category IN(SELECT Category FROM AllowedCategories)
```